# Getting an 'Update Case When' statement to do an imperfect match?

Tags: postgresql

Apologies if the title is confusing, unsure of the technical term. I'm working on getting a specific text, when inside a cell, to trigger a less sensitive match for updating the row. So when there's a "CH-%" inside of the cell, instead of matching to that particular "CH-N" or "CH-S" it'll look for any "CH-%" and then get back that value if the other columns match as well.

Here's my code:

```
update t_vessel_list_ballast
SET voyage_time = cast(b.travel_time as INTEGER),
time_source = 'region'
FROM t1_region b
WHERE CASE 
WHEN cast(b.travel_time as integer) > 100 THEN voyage_time = null
WHEN depart_region ilike 'CH-%' then 
    ('CH-%' ilike b.region 
    AND t_vessel_list_ballast.dest_region = b.region_arrive
    AND t_vessel_list_ballast.voyage_time is null)
    OR (t_vessel_list_ballast.dest_region = b.region 
    AND 'CH-%' ilike b.region_arrive
    AND t_vessel_list_ballast.voyage_time is null)
ELSE
    (t_vessel_list_ballast.depart_region = b.region 
AND t_vessel_list_ballast.dest_region = b.region_arrive
AND t_vessel_list_ballast.voyage_time is null)
OR (t_vessel_list_ballast.dest_region = b.region 
AND t_vessel_list_ballast.depart_region = b.region_arrive
AND t_vessel_list_ballast.voyage_time is null) END;
--end
```

This code will run, without any errors, but not do the intended result. Any suggestions on how to get it to do what i'm asking?

Comment: So you want `CH-%` to match CH-A or CH-Z but not CH-N and CH-S, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have a backwards condition..

change

```
'CH-%' ilike b.region
```

to

```
b.region ilike 'CH-%'
```